# Android: UI-Elements on lock screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, user-interface

How to have UI-Elements on the lock screen, like Spotify and Sound-Cloud App do it while music is playing?

[image: Android Lock-Screen with Spotify playing]

I have created a layout for inputting a text and a button to send it. How to let this input dialogue be on the lock screen, so one would be able to Input text to some app, without having to unlock the phone?
[image: Input Layout]

Here is the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeadline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Input Note to save:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etInputNote"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="type note"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnSaveNote"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeadline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvHeadline" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have googled multiple different keywords, unfortunately without finding a resource to learn about this.
If someone has a clue on how to achieve this, I would really appreciate it.